# What is the mathematical notation for mentioning variables names explicitly in a function assignment?

Tags: functions, notation

I have a function with two parameters: $f(s,t)$.

I want to assign to the function $\alpha$ and $\beta$: $f(\alpha,\beta)=5$.

But I don't want the reader to confuse $s$ and $t$ (the function's variables) from the values $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
I want to mention explcitly which is assigned to $s$ and which is assigned to $t$.

So I would like to denote it, for example, like this: $f(s=\beta,t=\alpha)=5$, or like this $f(s:\beta,t:\alpha)=5$.

Is there a convention for such a notation?
What is the correct notation?

Comment: Usually the function has standard names for variables, i.e., a polynomial is $f(X,Y)$ for variables $X,Y$. Then $f(\alpha,\beta)=5$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in K$ is clear, if we write $f\in K[X,Y]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the function $f(s,t)$ evaluated at point $(\alpha, \beta)$ as

$$f(s,t)|_{\alpha,\beta}=5$$

even your notation is also widely used i.e. $$f(s=\beta,t=\alpha)=5$$

*I don't think your last notation is used much for this purpose.*